# Asynchronous API call with knockout & data bind

Tags: knockout.js

First of all i am very new in knockout, i am mostly an angular person.

I have an application that stores all translations in local storage for every language in order to allow for localization.

I have in turn created a function that gets the language of the user (by doing an API call) and storing the results in-code, and then for the parameter you provide, the translation is obtained.

```
//GET TRANSLATION VALUE FROM LOCAL STORAGE
    self.getTranslation = function (name) {
        if (self.darwinTranslations == null || self.userLanguage == null) {
            self.darwinTranslations = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('darwin-translations'));
            var userLanguageURL = '/api/Language/GetCurrentUserLanguage';
            $.getJSON(userLanguageURL, function (data) {
                self.userLanguage = data;
                self.getTranslationAfterInitialization(name);
            });

        } else {
            self.getTranslationAfterInitialization(name);
        }
    }
    self.getTranslationAfterInitialization = function (name) {
        if (self.translatedLanguage == null || self.englishLanguage == null) {
            for (var index in self.darwinTranslations) {
                if (self.darwinTranslations.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
                    if (self.darwinTranslations[index].language == self.userLanguage) {
                        self.translatedLanguage = self.darwinTranslations[index];
                    }
                    if (self.darwinTranslations[index].language == 'en') {
                        self.englishLanguage = self.darwinTranslations[index];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        var translation = self.translatedLanguage.translations[name];
        if (translation == null) {
            translation = self.englishLanguage.translations[name];
        }
        return translation;
    }
```

Also, in my knockout there was code that used to setup the title of a header's table:

```
self.headers = [
    { title: 'Client Group', sortPropertyName: 'clientGroupName', asc: true, sortable: true },
    { title: 'Ghosting Project Name', sortPropertyName: 'name', asc: true, sortable: true },
    { title: 'Savings', asc: true, sortable: false },
    { title: 'Entegra Contact', sortPropertyName: 'pslContact', asc: true, sortable: false },
    { title: 'Sales Status', sortPropertyName: 'salesStatus', asc: true, sortable: false },
    { title: 'Last Updated', sortPropertyName: 'lastModified', asc: true, sortable: true },
    { title: 'Remove', sortPropertyName: 'remove', asc: true, sortable: false }
];
```

And of course in the HTML we were doing:

```
<table class="cdb-table" id="GhostingHomeTable" data-bind="visible: ghostingExercises().length > 0">
    <thead>
        <tr data-bind="foreach: headers">
            <th class="sortableHeader" data-bind="click: $parent.sort">
                <span data-bind="text: title" style="text-align: center;"></span>
                <!-- ko if: sortable -->
                <i style="text-align: right;" class="fa fa-sort"></i>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
```

What i want to do is change the title in the headers to the translated text, however any time i try to use the method i have added, because $.getJSON is async the column cannot be displayed in the f/e. I assume because the bindings were already applied by the time the async method returned.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I can where you fetch the user's language, and where you get the translations for that language. But I can't see at what point you're changing the headers to that language. 
Also, if you want the headers updated text to be reflected in the UI, you need to do either of these options: 1. make self.headers an observableArray, then update the entire array when you get the translations. 2. make just the title inside each header object an observable, and update them one by one when you get the translations.

Comment: this should be the place: `<span data-bind="text: title"` change to `<span data-bind="text: getTranslationAfterInitialization( title )"` if that is the function that will return the translation